# powershell gci/ls/dir getting 6 spots in mode

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm getting an odd formatting on my dir get-childitem in powershell:

```
Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
d----     7/31/2015 10:21 AM        <DIR> bin
-
d----     9/23/2015  8:47 AM        <DIR> dist
-
```

you can see that the mode is 6 spots for some reason and its causeing my listings to be double spaced.

i know i can throw it into a format-table -autosize,

but i'd like to know what is going on that changed things and if there is a way to permanently fix it...

Comment: Try to run clean PowerShell session `powershell -noprofile` and test again.

Comment: ok so the `powershell -noprofile` fixed it but i didn't learn anything and i lost some of my profile stuff (jump-location, posh-git)

- why was it there to begin with? what if i want it there?  is there a way to have it there and not have doublespaced gci?

Comment: just running `powershell` again also fixed it without losing my profile..  still want to know what was going on.
runing powershell again actually made it so the 6 spots fit in the GCI listing without the autosize...

Comment: @JeffMartin could you post *the exact* command you issued?

Comment: now if only someone would provide an answer rather than a comment, i could dish out some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell v5 adds support for symbolic links, so that adds sixth spot in `Mode` column. Likely, that some of module, you used, provide custom format data. For instance, you can see `<DIR>` in `Length` column, while PowerShell, by default, show nothing in `Length` column for directories. Possible, that that format data not yet updated for PowerShell v5 and set `Mode` column width to be 5, that make it to take two lines.